# .htaccess underscores to hyphens not working in my web server

Tags: .htaccess

I have seen many sample/tutorial regarding my case but when i use their working code, it's not doing anything to my URL.

I want to make this link example/lmp/property/jumeirah_parklarge_legacy_4brms/V0004221/ to example/lmp/property/jumeirah-parklarge-legacy-4brms/V0004221/

I also test the .htaccess code in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it gives me the right output URL but when test on my local server it doesn't redirect me to output URL.

Here's my code,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /lmp


    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]
    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]
    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]
    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2-$3-$4 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]
    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2-$3 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]
    RewriteRule ^lmp/property([^_]*)_(.*)$ lmp/property$1-$2 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_underscores} ^Yes$
    RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ lmp/$1 [R,L]



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /home
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /lmp/

    # recursive rule to replace _ by - from REQUEST_URI
    RewriteRule ^(property)/([^_]*)_+([^_]*_.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^(property)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ $1/$2-$3 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^../application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /home
</IfModule>
```